# MariaDB slave server shall connect to 127.0.0.1:3307 to reach master. SELinux says no. What do?

Tags: selinux

I have a MariaDB server on CentOS 7. The server shall play slave and replicate the a remote master server. The remote master server can be reached through an SSH tunnel. The SSH tunnel "inlet" is at 127.0.0.1:3307.

Connecting to this endpoint using the MariaDB client program works.

However, the MariaDB server is unable to connect. In the MySQL error log, one finds: `Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'replisql01@127.0.0.1:3307' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13 "Permission denied"), Internal MariaDB error code: 2003`.

Evidently, one immediately thinks of SELinux putting the kibosh on nonstandard connections outgoing from a MariaDB server.

After having put SELinux in permissive mode (edit `/etc/selinux/config` and reboot), the good phociform process manages to connect.

Let's examine `/var/log/audit/audit.log` which logs SELinux denial events (among other) using `ausearch` (further info on auditd in "[a brief introduction to auditd](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/)")

```
ausearch --comm mysqld
```

This gives entries like:

```
time->Wed Mar 21 18:52:53 2018
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1521654773.504:120): proctitle="/usr/sbin/mysqld"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1521654773.504:120): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-115 a0=41 a1=7fd1f4028ad0 a2=10 a3=72 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1342 auid=4294967295 uid=27 gid=27 euid=27 suid=27 fsuid=27 egid=27 sgid=27 fsgid=27 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="mysqld" exe="/usr/sbin/mysqld" subj=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1521654773.504:120): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=1342 comm="mysqld" dest=3307 scontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

([syscall 42](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) is `sys_connect`)

Very cool.

Now, I still have to read through [The Manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems) (and maybe it won't even help), so the question:

What command do I execute to let MariaDB connect to 127.0.0.1:3307? Because I want to [re-enable SELinux](https://stopdisablingselinux.com/).

Comment: Are there any relevant AVC type log entries? Do you have any custom audit rules in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux policies control every action that a process can execute on a given object - like files, devices, or sockets. If a daemon has been configured to listen or communicate using a nonstandard port, then the targeted policy denies that action, as it should. Labels are used to control ports. To find  the label for MariaDB, use `semanage`, and filter the results with `grep` using its well-known port number.

```
semanage port -l | grep 3306
```

This produces the following output.

```
mysqld_port_t tcp 1186, 3306, 63132-63164
```

To alter the rule for this label, use `semanage` again as follows for port 3307.

```
semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307
```

After executing the command above, check the rule again to see that 3307 is now permitted.

```
semanage port -l | grep 3307
```

This should show 3307 in the list of ports.

```
mysqld_port_t tcp 3307, 1186, 3306, 63132-63164
```

Comment: Testing this now...

Comment: Yes... it works. Thanks! Also added an additional answer as I have taken the time to look at the SELinux messaging subsystem (though all is not yet clear).

Answer (score 1):

If the package `setroubleshoot-server` has been installed (recommended), then the program `setroubleshootd` will be invoked via *dbus* from the audit daemon `auditd` (although indirectly) and given SELinux AVC records to process:

[image: SELinux Notification and Logging Cascade]

Note that `setroubleshootd` is not actually a "daemon" (it used to be) but an [invoked-on-activity program that exits again if all is quiet](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/28828.html).

`setroubleshootd` will log to syslog, and you will see AVC denial information. By default, this will end up in `/var/log/messages` unless `rsyslog` has been configured differently.

`setroubleshootd` will also notify *dbus* clients interested in SELinux events like `sealert` or GUI widgets.

Use `sealert` to examine AVC records. The man page says: *"The two most useful command line options are -l to "lookup" an alert ID and -a to "analyze" a log file."*

Looking at `/var/log/messages`, one will now see things like:

```
setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing mysqld from
name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 3307. For complete SELinux
messages run: sealert -l 90cd70e9-0bb2-4668-b165-d5be37e26b22
```

..and additional lines of very readable information which turn out to be a goo part of the output of `sealert -l 90cd70e9-0bb2-4668-b165-d5be37e26b22`.

So let's run `sealert -l 90cd70e9-0bb2-4668-b165-d5be37e26b22` -- this gives us good advice (not that this record was obtained while SELinux was enabled):

```
SELinux is preventing mysqld from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 3307.

*****  Plugin connect_ports (85.9 confidence) suggests   *********************

If you want to allow mysqld to connect to network port 3307
Then you need to modify the port type.
Do
# semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 3307
    where PORT_TYPE is one of the following: dns_port_t, dnssec_port_t,
    kerberos_port_t, mysqld_port_t, ocsp_port_t, tram_port_t.

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.33 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow nis to enabled
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'nis_enabled' boolean.
You can read 'None' man page for more details.
Do
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.33 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow mysql to connect any
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'mysql_connect_any' boolean.
You can read 'None' man page for more details.
Do
setsebool -P mysql_connect_any 1

*****  Plugin catchall (1.35 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that mysqld should be allowed name_connect access on the
port 3307 tcp_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'mysqld' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mysqld
# semodule -i my-mysqld.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0
Target Objects                port 3307 [ tcp_socket ]
Source                        mysqld
Source Path                   mysqld
Port                          3307
Host                          foobar.example.com
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     foobar.example.com
Platform                      Linux foobar.example.com
                              3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7
                              19:03:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   36
First Seen                    2018-03-22 16:04:59 CET
Last Seen                     2018-03-22 16:39:59 CET
Local ID                      90cd70e9-0bb2-4668-b165-d5be37e26b22

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1521733199.870:201): avc:  denied  { name_connect }
for  pid=1352 comm="mysqld" dest=3307
scontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0
tcontext=system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket


Hash: mysqld,mysqld_t,unreserved_port_t,tcp_socket,name_connect
```

So, with **85.9 confidence** ("I'll be baaack!")

"If you want to allow mysqld to connect to network port 3307 then you need to modify the port type. Do `semanage port -a -t PORT_TYPE -p tcp 3307`" where PORT_TYPE is `mysqld_port_t`!